# GMT time to Seconds

Tags: c

I am implementing a cache in a proxy server. I am storing Expires: field from the response of request and next time if same request comes then i will compare the Expires time with current time.
Now I am stuck here. how should I convert Expire time format to seconds and then take a difference?
Is that any other way to get time difference ?

Format for Expire time is :
    `Sat, 10 Nov 2012 07:05:26 GMT`

Suppose I have two time, how can I compare two times in `GMT?`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct tm t;
    time_t seconds;
    const char *expire = "Sat, 10 Nov 2012 07:05:25 GMT";
    strptime(expire, "%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S", &t);
    seconds = mktime(&t);
    printf("%lu\n", seconds);
}
```

Note that your times must be in GMT time since strptime() ignores the time zone (at least on Linux). You may also need to set your locale to the same locale used for your input times.

Comment: Can you give some explanation with your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel See the description of the `strptime()` function somewhere online. Ditto for `mktime()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation has it, you could use the [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) function to convert that string to a `struct tm`, then [`mktime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) to convert *that* to a `time_t` for easy comparison.